# How to change the tint of a JournalingSuggestionsPicker

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, journalsuggestion

As it says. It defaults to system blue, but I found no way to modify it.

The accentColor or tint won't work on the JournalingSuggestions sheet.

```
  JournalingSuggestionsPicker {
        Text("H")
    } onCompletion: { suggestion in

    }
    .accentColor(.yellow)
```

EDIT: Just to make it more clear, the code above will change the text H to yellow. But What I need is to change the tint color for the sheet that pops up. I guess the issue is that the hosting view has a tint defaults to blue, but I cannot figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

some View Sets the tint effect associated with specific content in a list.

```
func listItemTint(ListItemTint?)
```

some View Sets a fixed tint color associated with specific content in a list.

```
func listItemTint(Color?)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

1. Modifier for Foreground Color:

If the component supports changing the foreground color, you can use the foregroundColor modifier in SwiftUI to change the tint. For example:

```
 JournalingSuggestionsPicker()
    .foregroundColor(.yourTintColor)
```

2.Custom Styling:

Check if the component provides customization through a styling API. SwiftUI often uses style modifiers to allow customization. For example:

```
JournalingSuggestionsPicker().pickerStyle(YOUR_CUSTOM_STYLE())
```

3.Direct Access to Tint Color:

If you have access to the internal components or layers of the picker, you might directly set the tint color using UIKit or AppKit.

```
struct YourJournalingSuggestionsPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let picker = JournalingSuggestionsPicker()
        picker.tintColor = .yourTintColor
        return picker
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Lovely suggestions. But non of them works o.o

Comment: Yep, tried it all. None works.